# The host don't allow events on MySQL, what is the best alternative

Tags: php, mysql

I need events for MySQL database, But I realize that I can't have event for the host's level I bought. The only solution that I come up with is: 1- create a php page with a single button in it. 2- put the event codes into this page 3- put this page in a password protected folder 4- and every hour, open the page and hit the button.
Not a good idea? I know. So, what is the best alternative?

Comment: Schedule the mysql event

Comment: I asked hosting company for event: "I need Event for my databases but I can't enable it. please help me." and They told me: 'We do not offer this option. You can use regular cronjobs instead (Level 9 or higher).' My hosting plan is not Level 9 or higher. so I can't use corn job either.

Comment: check my cron job answer

Comment: Find a provider that isn't so limiting, or... use an external server or service like AWS Lambda (which now has cron capability) to hit your web site with a scheduled request sent to the special page that does the maintenance work.

Answer (score 1):

As Jim in the comment. Try to use Cron Job and call your PHP Script for every hour is my alternative answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
# This file would be say, '/usr/local/bin/run.php'
// code
echo "I'm CRON Script"
```

Add a Cron Job Command Structure:

```
Minutes [0-59]
|   Hours [0-23]
|   |   Days [1-31]
|   |   |   Months [1-12]
|   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]
|   |   |   |   |
*   *   *   *   * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

Command Example:

```
* 1 * * * php-path -f php-script-path &> /dev/null
* 1 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/run.php &> /dev/null
```

Add Permission through CHMOD command.

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/run.php
```

Reference:
[How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Answer (score 0):

Check the current process list by below command / enable event scheduler.

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
or
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

[image]

Refer the Below URLs
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/

Comment: I run it in phpMyAdmin and the error is: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation.

Comment: request your server admin to do this or get access and run it

Comment: I ask them how can I turn it on, and they say: 'You need a higher level of hosting plan to have event_scheduler'

Comment: @coolesterman So upgrade to that hosting plan. Or to another web host that doesn't impose this sort of arbitrary limitation.

Comment: @duskwuff that would be costly. so there really is no way to solve this. I guess I should stick to my own outdated solution. :(

Comment: why cant u try cron job

Comment: As I said the hosting company told me, to use corn job, the hosting plane version 9 or higher is needed. I got version 4.