# CALLing a mySQL Stored Procedure from a PHP script - no error but not executing?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, adminer

- UPDATE AT THE END

I'm following this [Automatic Partition Maintenance in MySQL](http://www.geoffmontee.com/automatic-partition-maintenance-in-mysql-and-mariadb-part-3/) tutorial, which details a generic method for removing and adding mySQL table partitions based on date ranges.

The idea is that you can jettison older table data automatically after a certain length of time, and create new table partitions for current data as needed.

However, since my site will likely be hosted on a "shared" provider package, it seems likely that mySQL events will be unavailable to me.

So I'm cross fertilizing the Stored Procedures described in the first tutorial, with an alternative method of invoking them using the method detailed in this Stack Overflow answer, with some modifications: [Partition maintainance script for Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34564047/2577646)

On my local test machine, I want to run the PHP script as a CRON job from [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/).

When I run the Stored Procedures from [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) (which has similar functionality to phpMyAdmin), using the [mySQL test database](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db), they execute as expected - partitions are deleted, and the whole process takes a couple of minutes to complete.

However, when I run my modified PHP script from Webmin as a CRON job, nothing seems to happen. There are no errors, but the script returns immediately with "OK".

Similarly, when I run the script from my LAMP machine's shell, it immediately returns with "OK".

This is the PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_username', 'my_password', 'employees');
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL perform_partition_maintenance('employees', 'titles', 3, 216, 5)") or die('Query fail: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
if ($result)
  echo "OK";
else
  echo "FAIL";
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions about where I might be going wrong.

---

**UPDATE**

In line with Nick's suggestion, I've been adding a lot of debug statements. I went a slightly different route because it was a bit easier to do - lots of new "into outfile" statements.

But what I've observed has baffled me. A small segment of the Stored Procedure is below:

```
OPEN cur1;
    read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cur1 INTO current_partition_name;
      IF done THEN
         LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;

      IF ! @first AND p_seconds_to_sleep > 0 THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('Sleeping for ', p_seconds_to_sleep, ' seconds');
        SELECT SLEEP(p_seconds_to_sleep);
      END IF;

      SELECT CONCAT('Dropping partition: ', current_partition_name);

      ...

      SET @first = FALSE;
    END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
```

This is all taken, unmodified, from the web tutorial at Geoff Montee's page, and works flawlessly in other contexts (i.e., within Adminer, from the sql console - just not in combination with a PHP script).
However, when I comment out the line that says:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Dropping partition: ', current_partition_name);
```

Everything works just fine, but the script chokes when I put that line back in. I can't make any sense of this. Particularly since - in testing - I'm writing out "current_partition_name" into a file on disk for the first three iterations of the loop, and referencing the string in that situation doesn't cause any issues. It's very odd.

[This other (apparently unresolved) stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820329/called-mysql-stored-procedure-via-php-does-not-execute-properly) sounds somewhat similar.

Comment: Are you sure the PHP user has appropriate privileges to perform the operations in the procedure?

Comment: Hey Nick, appreciate the suggestion - that's the thought that's been niggling away at me. I'm a novice with Linux, but I've used "exec('whoami'), and this returns "root"

Comment: It's not who you are on Linux, but what privileges in MySQL that `my_username` has been granted that is important here.

Comment: Thanks again: the username I'm passing in here is also "root" (at least, on my local test machine)

Comment: Something very odd is going on - or at least it seems odd to me. I created a simple Stored Procedure which just performs a SELECT with a string constant, and then uses "into file..." to write out this string to disk. Calling this from the same PHP script **DOES** create the output file. Again, running the other Stored Procedures (the "real" ones) from within Adminer works flawlessly (also from the mysql> console), so it's not a syntax error. Very confusing.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to put some debugging `SELECT` statements into the procedure and output their results in your script. Note that you'll need to use `mysqli_real_query` or `mysqli_multi_query` to get the returned data (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php)

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll give that a try, and see what I can come up with

Comment: @AMarch you obviously found an answer to your question. (It is not possible). Please use the way the site is designed to let others know. I.E. Answer your own question instead of using an edit on your question.

Comment: Appreciate the heads-up Luuklag, I'll modify the page and observe this protocol in future.

Answer (score 0):

Belatedly, I've become aware that partitioning is not available when a table has foreign keys. I'm not sure how I missed this fundamental detail when I was first exploring partitioning as an option.

It's very unfortunate because it renders the entire exercise redundant. I'll have to investigate some sort of a solution involving conventional table deletes, with all of the associated headaches.

---

Separately, I'm not closer to understanding why commenting out that particular line from Geoff Montee's Stored Procedure was pivotal in allowing the function to run successfully when invoked from PHP. I'd be tempted to put it down to an interpreter bug (I'm running mySQL 5.5.62 in my test environment), but as mentioned previously, the Stored Procedure executes flawlessly when initiated from Adminer.